# How do I manage two different authentication in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

since laravel's built in authentication uses user model? For example I want to separate the admin from the user so I will build two different layers in my application, the admin and the user. How can I achieve this to laravel since it's default auth uses users table and user model?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there's no real need to separate the two. Administrators and typical users can exist on the same database table, because they are both `users` but can have different `permissions`.

It seems like you're just looking for a typical permissions system (ACL). There's multiple packages available that can help you handle this.

- [Orchestra Auth](https://github.com/orchestral/auth)
- [Sentinel](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel)
- [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)

Comment: There's also a basic permissions system built into [Laravel 5.1.11](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization). I haven't used it and don't know how it compares to Entrust or Sentinel, but that is a first-party option

Comment: Yup you're right, the difference is that laravel's built in authorization is through hard-coded 'gates' and would take some work to implement on the database side. Though I'm really looking forward to a pre-built system using laravel's new authorization system.

Answer (score 0):

Normally as an admin is still an user you give them a role column and let say you have : users, moderators and admins. Then you got role 0,1,2 for them. Just make it an enum and if you need to check in Laravel use : `Auth::user()->role == 2` for example of admin rights :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!